# Format the M language in Power Bi Query

Tags: format, powerbi, conditional-formatting, code-formatting, powerbi-desktop

Do anyone know how to format the Power Bi back-end query, I did not find any thing only.

Like for JSON we have json formater online.

Can not we do the same, for DAX and **M- Language** wanted to format the query so that i can read properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is https://powerqueryformatter.com/ - it is helping me format Power Query M language

Comment: I like that! I've also tried using the Visual Code extension for .pq

Comment: yes, this site helps more than a build in Power BI options. thanks

Answer (score 2):

For DAX, you can use https://www.daxformatter.com/ - provided by the SQLBI team.

Comment: Also what about m-programming language by Microsoft. I used this for advance editor in power BI, a lot of code and hard to deal with.

Comment: I'm not aware of any similar automatic code formatting service for Power Query language - turning on intellisense (preview) helps, though.

Comment: Yes but not helping in mush extend.. Thanks for your help #Olly

Answer (score 0):

Until now, i was able to see few option in Power BI advance editor, that is helping me a bit not 100% formatted code.

[image]

Best suggestion would be is to use text editor like sublime and do format your query on building stage, that would give you more clarification if you are working on the Power Bi side. Thanks you.

If someone knows, how to do this query format start to end the whole query, please let me know.